# Android Camera2: CONTROL_AF_STATE always 0 for CONTROL_AF_MODE_MACRO

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am trying to detect when camera has focused (or has stopped trying to) so I am calling `result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE)`in *onCaptureCompleted* method of callback.

It kind of works for mode *AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE*, camera reports CONTROL_AF_STATE 1 or 2 (CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_SCAN or CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_LOCKED), which is nice.

However when camera is switched to *AF_MODE_MACRO*, then reported CONTROL_AF_STATE is always 0 (INNACTIVE) no matter what happens. I was trying to refer to [1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#CONTROL_AF_STATE) but probably I do not get it right.

Further info: when changing modes between *AF_MODE_MACRO* and *AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE* I always start new capture session like this:

```
private void configCaptureSession(boolean macroModeNew) {
this.macroMode = macroModeNew;
try {
  // Wanna macro?
  if (macroMode) {
    LOGGER.d( "MACRO ON","");
    previewRequestBuilder.set(
            CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_MACRO);
    }

  else {
    // Continuous AF
    LOGGER.d( "MACRO OFF","");
    previewRequestBuilder.set(
            CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

  }

  // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
  previewRequest = previewRequestBuilder.build();
  LOGGER.d( "SETTING NEW SESSION","");

  captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
      previewRequest, captureCallback, backgroundHandler);

} catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
  LOGGER.e(e, "Exception!");
}
```

}

captureCallback:

```
 private final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback =
  new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCaptureProgressed(
        final CameraCaptureSession session,
        final CaptureRequest request,
        final CaptureResult partialResult) {}

    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(
        final CameraCaptureSession session,
        final CaptureRequest request,
        final TotalCaptureResult result) {

        afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);

        LOGGER.i("FOKKUS-MODE:"+result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_MODE));
        LOGGER.i("FOKKUS:"+result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE));

    }

  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your device list support for AF_MODE_MACRO in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#CONTROL_AF_AVAILABLE_MODES ?

If not, then this is expected as you're trying to use a non-supported focusing mode.

If it is supported, the next issue is that I don't see you issuing an [AF trigger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER) command anywhere.  Have you looked at the state transition tables for AF_STATE here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#CONTROL_AF_STATE ?

For AF_AUTO and AF_MACRO, you have to trigger AF when you want a focus pass, and then wait for AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED or NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED.

The continuous modes don't require a trigger to focus, which is why you're seeing something happening with them.

Comment: Thank you Eddy for the answer! I was not aware of the fact that I have to issue AF Triger. Because autofocus seems to be working anyway. Actually i cannot find any kind of good description/tutorial how to that and work with Camera2 Api in general. Based on the code snippets in my post, could you please suggest good aproach?

Comment: You can take a look at the Camera2Basic sample from Google: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic